# meteor : login with google (how display profile user?)

Tags: meteor

i had create login system with google Api but i have problem to display picture and name user. That is my code. Please anyone help me.

```
  // js
if (Meteor.isClient){
     Meteor.subscribe ('user');


 Template.body.helpers({
   firstName: function(){
    var user = Meteor.user(); 
    if (user) {
      return user.services.google.given_name;    
    } 
   },

   profileURL: function() {
    var user = Meteor.user(); 
    if (user) {
      return user.services.google.picture; 
    } 
 }
});



     //server
Meteor.publish("user", function () {
  return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},
                           {fields: {'other': 1, 'things': 1}});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save values with `Accounts.onCreateUser` and save the relevant information.

```
//in server
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options,user){
    if (typeof(user.services.google) != "undefined") {
        user.email = user.services.google.email;
        user.profilePicture = user.services.google.picture;
        user.username = user.services.google.name;
    }
  return user;
});
```

Then you can return those fields using {{}}.

```
{{currentUser.username}} // returns email of the current user
```

Also, you need routing for defining routes. Check [iron:router](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/) and [flow:router](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the desired values to the user document in the collection.

This code builds the user object with the common values from the login services for meteor.loginwith [**facebook**, **google**,**twitter**]. Then adds it to the mongo collection for the users.

Now all this data will be accessible from the currentUser object.

*You can remove the values or networks you're not using.*

```
Accounts.onCreateUser( ( options, user )=> {

    user.profile  = getProfile( user );

    function getProfile( user ) {

        let service = user.services;
        let network = _.keys( service )[ 0 ];
        let data    = service[ network ];
        let profile = {};

        if ( network === 'facebook' ) {
            profile.network = network;
            profile.id      = data.id;
            profile.email   = data.email;
            profile.name    = data.name;
            profile.locale  = data.locale;
            profile.gender  = data.gender;
            profile.picture = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' + data.id + '/picture?type=square';
        }

        else if ( network === 'google' ) {
            profile.network = network;
            profile.id      = data.id;
            profile.email   = data.email;
            profile.name    = data.name;
            profile.locale  = data.locale;
            profile.picture = data.picture;
        }

        else if ( network === 'twitter' ) {
            profile.network = network;
            profile.id      = data.id;
            profile.email   = data.email;
            profile.name    = data.screenName;
            profile.locale  = data.lang;
            profile.picture = data.profile_image_url_https;
        }

        let value        = {};
        value[ network ] = profile;
        return value;
    }

    Meteor.users.update( user._id, {
        $set: {
            profile: user.profile
        }
    } );

    return user;

} );
```